# How do you manipulate the values inside arrays within the main program when using class instances and member functions?

Tags: c++

I was wondering how to place my array arr[STACK_CAPACITY] inside the main program so it pushes and pops the values in the stack. Currently I'm getting a memory leak error and the chars aren't getting changed as I wanted it to.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define STACK_CAPACITY 1000

char arr[STACK_CAPACITY];
int index = 0;


class Stack
{

public:
    Stack(); // constructor for a stack
    void push(char c); // adds c to the top of the stack
    char pop(); // removes top element
    char top(); // returns the top element
    bool isEmpty(); // returns true iff the stack is empty
    bool isFull(); // returns true iff the stack is full
    ~Stack(); // destructor for a stack
};

 Stack::Stack() { }

void Stack::push(char c) {
    if (!isFull()) {
        arr[index] = c;
        index++;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Index has exceeded." << "\n";
    }
}

char Stack::pop() {
    char removed;

    if (!isEmpty()) {
        index--;
        removed = arr[index];
    }
    else {
        cout << "Stack can go down any further." << "\n";
    }

    return removed;
}

char Stack::top() {
    return arr[index];
}

bool Stack::isEmpty() {
    bool all_empty;

    if (index == -1) {
        all_empty = true;
    }
    else {
        all_empty = false;
    }
    return all_empty;
}


bool Stack::isFull() {
    bool all_full;

    if (index == 1000) {
        all_full = true;
    }
    else {
        all_full = false;
    }
    return all_full;
}

Stack::~Stack() { }


int main()
{   
    string inp;
    Stack instance;

    cout << "Please enter a string: ";

    while(getline(cin,inp)) {

        if (inp == "^D") {
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)inp.length(); i++) {
            //cout << inp[i] << "\n";

            arr[i] = inp[i];
            instance.push(arr[i]);
            cout << instance.pop();
        }
        cout << "\n";

        //for (int j = inp.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        //  cout << inp[j];

        //}
        //cout << "\n";

        cout << "Please enter a string: ";
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "memory leak error". I see no dynamic allocation taking place here. There's nothing to leak. Also, you need to edit your question, and properly indent and format your code. The haphazard indentation, and bad formatting makes the shown code nearly incomprehensible.

Comment: No never mind I'm not getting a leak error. It's just not printing out anything at the moment. There are no letters appearing and I was thinking it could be because the chars weren't put inside the array yet, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why do you have global variables for things that should be member variables inside the class? Why are you modifying the array in the `main` function *and* using the class member functions (e.g. `arr[i] = inp[i]` followed by `instance.push(arr[i])` makes no sense).

Comment: It's not printing in reversed order and I'm not quite sure why. It might have to do with my pop function but I dont see anything wrong with it so I thought it might be because of my array and how I'm declaring it.

Comment: Fyi: `removed` is *indeterminate* when your `pop` encounters an empty stack condition, and as such, so shall be your function result returned to the caller. And related, as-written this won't put data out in reverse order. You're pushing and popping for each loop iteration. Your stack never has more than a single element.

Comment: Oh okay so instead it could just be inp[i] instead of arr[i]. And it would still work fine when I placed it ino my pop function as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...how to place my array arr[STACK_CAPACITY] inside the main program...

You don't; it doesn't belong in the `main` program; it should be a member of the `Stack` class. Among the multitude of things wrong or ill-advised in this code:

- `arr` and `index` should not be modified in `main`; that's why your class provides member function access. - `arr` should be a member of `Stack`
- `index` should be a member of `Stack`
- `index` should be an unsigned data type (it reflects both an index *and* a magnitude).
- `index` should reference where the *next* item is stored, which means a value of `0` indicates an empty stack, and a value of `CAPACITY` indicates a full stack.
- `main` should push all string chars into the stack *before* looping to pop them off (which will give you the reverse order you seem to be seeking).
- `isFull()`, `isEmpty()` and `top()` should all be `const`, as none of them require a mutable object to perform.
- `pop()` should return `void` (similar to the standard library).

As simple as I could make it, all of the above applied result in:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Stack
{
    static constexpr size_t CAPACITY = 1000;
    char arr[CAPACITY];
    size_t index = 0;

public:
    void push(char c);      // adds c to the top of the stack
    void pop();             // removes top element
    char top() const;       // returns the top element
    bool isEmpty() const;   // returns true iff the stack is empty
    bool isFull() const;    // returns true iff the stack is full
};

void Stack::push(char c)
{
    if (index < CAPACITY)
        arr[index++] = c;
    else
        std::cerr << "idx has exceeded.\n";
}

void Stack::pop()
{
    if (index > 0)
        --index;
    else
        std::cerr << "attempt to pop an empty stack\n";
}

char Stack::top() const
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Attempt to fetch top of empty stack\n";
        return 0;
    }
    return arr[index-1];
}

bool Stack::isEmpty() const
{
    return index == 0;
}

bool Stack::isFull() const
{
    return index == CAPACITY;
}


int main()
{
    Stack instance;
    std::string inp;

    std::cout << "Please enter a string: ";

    while(getline(std::cin,inp) && !inp.empty())
    {
        for (auto x : inp)
            instance.push(x);

        for (; !instance.isEmpty(); instance.pop())
            std::cout << instance.top();
        std::cout << '\n';

        std::cout << "Please enter a string: ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output**

```
Please enter a string: Simple string
gnirts elpmiS
Please enter a string: Another string
gnirts rehtonA
Please enter a string: 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**Disclaimer**

Of course, standard disclaimer applies: Unless this is for academia or some self-directed tutorial, the container adapter [`std::stack<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) is an obvious choice to use over rolling your own.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I guess the main problem was that I wasn't declaring the array inside the class. I was extremely lost haha.